# remove data from session when user navigates from current page

Tags: c#, asp.net

Please help me with following problem.

I am implementing credit card functionality and I want to remove data from session when user navigates from current page to other page.

Comment: Edit the question tell us what u have done so far, it will help to solve ur problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to remove session data. May be you can read [this reference document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525095%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and [Session.Contents.RemoveAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524866%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for more understanding. Also, you can use `Session.Clear()` to remove session variables from session state colelction

Answer (score 0):

Use `Session.Clear()` to remove all values from Session state collection.

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
Session.Abandon()
```

see this coming from microsoft
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524310%28v=vs.90%29.aspx